# How to debug ROS 2 programs in vscode

Tags: ros2, vscode

I usually debug my ROS 2 programs using print statements and echoing to topics. Is there a better way to debug ROS 2 programs so that I can see the value of certain variables or even stop the program at a specific line?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please use the [ROS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros) in vscode. It allows and performs all the tasks you mentioned above. Feel free to read the documentation and look online for tutorials.